# Firefox Firebug update has removed css path facility. Where can I find it?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug

The latest version of Firefox has led to the removal of a useful tool in the Firebug extension which I use a lot in website design, namely the **copy css path**. I used to open Firebug and select the required element. By right hand clicking I could copy and paste the correct css path to be able to edit this element.

I've played around with the new version including adding Firepath but I can't seem to find how to simply copy and paste the path I need. This was the most important tool so it seems odd it's been removed.

Can anyone advise me how to get it back? Or another way to do find the path simply and quickly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Via [the Firebug homepage](http://getfirebug.com/):

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead, which ship with Firebug.next

The feature you are looking for is supported in the native Firefox developer tools. Find the element in the element selector, and then look under "Copy" for "CSS Selector" in the context menu.

[image: Firefox Inspector]

Comment: What you have shown does not give the same results as the firebug Copy CSS Path command.
I have just followed the instructions above and the result was a very short selector (probably a unique selector) "#photo_130 > span:nth-child(1)".
What I am looking for is the complete CSS Path. I've uninstalled firebug so can't show you an example, but it is typically very long, but very, very useful.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who replied.  Anita is right - the option to copy the complete css path is not available but thanks to Quentin for offering help :)  It seems we need to wait for an update before this vital tool is reinstated.  It really makes my web developer work difficult without it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Quentin, Firebug is officially discontinued and it does not work anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled.
What you see are actually the Firefox DevTools, which do not provide the same functionality as Firebug yet (as of Firefox 50.1).

They have a *Copy* > *CSS Selector* option, which copies a short CSS selector, though an option to copy the full CSS selector is still missing. It is requested in [bug 1323700](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323700).